# How to store integer numbers to MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, integer, store

I am doing a website for some reporting purpose, so I need to store data to MySQL using php. everything is good but I can't store integers/numbers to the database. I guess there's something wrong with my code. Please help me out.

html code:

```
 <div id = "forms">
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" form action="add_data.php" method="post" >

  <li> <label for = "Injured_D" > No. of Injured Driver: </label>
  <input "type = "text" name = "Injured_D" id = "Injured_D" />  
  </li>

<div id = "submit"><button type="submit" >Submit</button> </div><br>
</form>
```

php code:

```
// escape variables for security
$injured_D = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['injured_D']);
$sql="INSERT INTO abc (injured_D) VALUES ('$injured_D')";
```

MySQL Settings:

Type: int(30)

Collation: none

Comment: How big is the number ?

Comment: not big, as you can see it's injured drivers. so it can range from 0 to 20 (max)

Comment: Try this query directly in you mysql as `insert into abc(injured_D) values ('20');` and see what happens. This should work, now you have some issue on the PHP part you need to use error log for mysqli to find out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had typo within your code

```
<input "type = "text" name = "Injured_D" id = "Injured_D" />  
                              ^^
```

It should be

```
<input "type = "text" name = "injured_D" id = "Injured_D" />  
                              ^^
```

You were passing **Injured_D** within `POST` and getting it with name **injured_D**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$sql="INSERT INTO abc (injured_D) VALUES ('$injured_D')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO abc (injured_D) VALUES ($injured_D)";
```

Comment: It does not matter if you quote the integer values for `int` datatype.

Comment: nope, it causes syntax error. it says Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', 'Motor Collision' , 'Head Collision', '', 'Uncontrolled', 'Two-way' , 'No',' at line 2"

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO abc (injured_D) VALUES ('$injured_D')";
```

should be

```
$sql="INSERT INTO abc (injured_D) VALUES ($injured_D)";
```

without ' '

Comment: It does not matter if you quote the integer values for int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Change from :

```
$injured_D = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['injured_D']);
```

To :

```
$injured_D = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Injured_D']);
```